gphoto2 get return fom terminal screen to file
Gphoto2 works i can issue commands as below.
call(["gphoto2","--get-config","shutterspeed"]) this outputs to my terminal / screen ok.
It displays all the shutter setting and the cameras current shutter speed setting.
i need to return / get this current setting into a python variable.
How do i get the terminal information displayed into a file or variable.
Please note, i am a relative newbe.
Searched everywhere. It should be easy ?
Using python3 / Tkinter etc / running a pi3 /connected via VNC
Please advise.
I realize this is not really a gphoto2 question.
Thanks any pointers would be good.
Madbudgi

So are you asking about assigning the result to a python variable, or to a shell variable? to write to a file from python or from the shell? Please [edit] your question with details of how you are running the command and what your end goal is.
